# Recursive callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, amazon-dynamodb

So I'm trying to write a function which gets the params and calls the [scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) method of DynamoDB which returns the paginated result and also I'm getting `limit` as an input from params, so I don't want to call my scan function recursively to get all data, instead I want to get data as much as `limit` has been passed as a param. I tried the following block of code, but it seems my logic is not right! could you please help me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function scan(params, total, callback) {
    dynamo.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, data);
        } else {
            if (((!params.Limit || (params.Limit && total.length < params.Limit)))
                    && data.Items && data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                (function(data) {
                    scan(params, data.Items.concat(data.Items), function(err, result) {
                        data.Items = data.Items.concat(result.Items);
                        if (result.LastEvaluatedKey)
                            data.LastEvaluatedKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
                        callback(err, data);
                    });
                } (data));
            } else {
                callback(err, total); //Here it says undefined is not a function
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Calling by the following code:

```
//params is stuffed with needed parameters for scan method of DynamoDB
scan(params,[],function(err, data){
    //Processing data here
})
```

Comment: How are you calling scan() the first time?

Comment: Helpful tidbit: your `(function(data) {` closure is not necessary.

Comment: Are you trying to grab a certain amount of items? Or just limit how many items get evaluated?  DynamoDB's Scan API has a parameter (Limit), which will do the latter.

Comment: @RaymondLin I'm so happy you know the logic of scan in DynamoDB; yes I do know DynamoDB `limit` in `scan` limits how many items get evaluated, and based on the documentation the max limit is 100, so it checks the first 100 items, and it returns whatever items are fulfilled based on the condition, but that's not really what I want I want to grab exactly `n` items which are fulfilled based on my conditions!

Comment: @RaymondLin So I want terminate my recursive function once I grab n number of items, although here I'm using the same number for both limit which is used for dynamodb and the number of items which I want to grab; I really appreciate your help ...

Comment: @RaymondLin I correct one of my sentences; "based on the documentation the max limit is 1MB", I appreciate your help in my algorithm...

Comment: @user3421904 When calling `callback(err, total);`, it will call `function(err, data) { ... }` like this: `function(err = err, data = total) { ... }`. Is that right? Also, if inside the callback, you are calling `scan` again (recursively), make sure that you're passing the calback function to its third argument, or it will end up with the `undefined is not a function` error!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that I wrote, let me know if it suits your use case or if you have any questions.

```js
/**
  * This method will scan continue to scan until
  *     1) There are no more items (LastEvaluatedKey is null)
  *     2) We have retrieved N items from paginated scan
  * If we find more than N, we take the first N items.
  **/
function scanWithItemLimit(params, n, callback, items) {
    db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var leftover = n - data.Items.length;
            var itemsCopy = items ? items : [];
            if (leftover > 0) {
                itemsCopy = itemsCopy.concat(data.Items);
                var paramsCopy = params;
                paramsCopy.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                if (params.ExclusiveStartKey) {
                    scanWithItemLimit(paramsCopy, leftover, callback, itemsCopy);
                } else {
                    callback(err, itemsCopy);
                }
            } else {
                if (n != 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        itemsCopy.push(data.Items[i]);
                    }
                }
                callback(err, itemsCopy);
            }
        }
    });
}

var pfunc = function(err, items) { console.log(err, items); };
params = {TableName: "Table"};
scanWithItemLimit(params, 5, pfunc);
```